# Is this a valid bijection from this set of permutations to the set of bracket nestings of order $n$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, catalan-numbers

I'm trying to prove that the set of permutations of $[n]$ which do not contain a decreasing subsequence of order $\geq 3$ is equal to the $n^{th}$ [Catalan Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). One of the many things that the Catalan Numbers count is the set of valid *parentheses* of order $n$, so for example
$$()()\text{ and }(())$$
are the valid parentheses (or bracket nestings) of order $2$, equal to the $2^{\text{nd}}$ Catalan Number, $2$. Here is an attempted bijection I've tried:

- Write the permutation down in its normal form, ie. $$1324$$
- If an element is not the first element of any decreasing subsequence, parenthesize it. $$(1)3(2)(4)$$
- Parenthesize the decreasing subsequence (in case an element is part of more than one, then the longest). $$(1)(3(2))(4)$$
- Remove the elements to obtain $$1324\mapsto()(())()$$

I've tried this for the permutations of order $3$, and seems to work:

$$123\mapsto()()()$$
$$132\mapsto()(())$$
$$213\mapsto(())()$$
$$231\mapsto((()))$$
$$312\mapsto(()())$$

If this bijection is valid, then my initial proposition is proven.

Is this a valid bijection?

EDIT: It also works for $n=4$. Could the proof of bijection follow from the uniqueness of the transposition decomposition?

Comment: I'm not sure this is completely specified.  Consider $4231$;  $4$ is the first element of $2$ decreasing sequences of length $2$.  I guess that you would want to parenthesize this as $(4(2))(3(1))\to(())(())$, but I don't see how the rules cover this case. Why parenthesize $42$ rather than $43$?  Or why not?

Comment: @saulspatz $4231$ wouldn't be part of the bijection, as it contains decreasing subsequences of order $3$, namely $431$ and $421$. We're only considering permutations with decreasing subsequences of order (at most) $2$.

Comment: My mistake, thank you.

Comment: I think it should be more clear what you mean by "Parenthesize the decreasing subsequence, in case an element is part of more than one, the longest". Because in the examples "231", after the first step we have "23(1)" and after that there are two subsequences left, 2-1 and 3-1, but you parenthesize both, even when by your wording I'd have assumed you'd only parenthesize 2-1 because is the longest that $1$ is in. Maybe you only consider this rule left-to-right or maybe I'm misreading it, but a clarification would help.

Comment: @AnilCh I meant to parenthesize the longest subsequence with respect to the first element of the subsequence. Since all decreasing subsequences are of length $2$, an element is either the first element or the second element of the subsequence. So in that example, the 'longest'  wrt $3$ is $(3\ 1)$, and so you would parenthesize $(3\ 1)$ and not $(3\ 2)$. Similarly, the longest wrt $2$ is $(2\ 1)$, so that is also parenthesized. $1$ is only the ending element, so we don't care about the 'longest' subsequence it is in.

Comment: Which permutation on 4 covers $( () () () )$?

Comment: @JMP $4123\mapsto (4(1)(2)(3))\mapsto (()()())$.

Comment: This paper proves a similar result:  https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.2691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've defined the forward map from permutations of $n$ with no decreasing sequences of length $>3$, and it's relatively easy to see that always works. So all that's left is to define the reverse mapping and see that that always works in order to prove a bijection.

In any valid string, one of two things must be true:

1. The string can be split into two or more substrings, such that each substring is a valid string. (Ie. there are the same number of opening and closing brackets within each substring.)
2. The string is of the form (substring). (That is, there's a pair of brackets which surround a valid substring.)

**Proof:** Read along the string and keep a running tally of the function *#left brackets - #right brackets*. If it's ever zero before the end of the substring, case 1 is true. Otherwise, it must always be $\ge1$ (by definition, it can't be $<0$.) So, it is always wrapped in a set of parentheses which are never escaped from the entire length of the string, and case 2 is true. $\square$

We can use this to solve the problem recursively. In each case:

1. The string splits into 2 substrings, and every element in the left substring must be less than every element in the right substring, otherwise there would be a bracket that wouldn't close, and it wouldn't be a valid substring. (If it split into $n$ substrings, then each substring would contain numbers greater than all the substrings that came before, and less than all the substrings that came after.)
2. There is a pair of brackets surrounding a valid substring - this implies the first element is greater than the last. Further, they must be consecutive, since if the sequence $[a,b,c,...,i]$ had another number $k$ such that $a>k>i$, then that would be a decreasing sequence of length $3$, which is forbidden. From there, you can strip the sequence of its outer brackets, which is equivalent to solving the string without it's first element. Your result will look like $[b,c,...,i]$ - from there, take every element of your list that's $>i$, and add 1 to it, and prepend the string with $i+1$, which solves your original string.

That second case took a lot more thought than I expected to to make sure it worked correctly, and I'm not sure I explained it well. Still, I enjoyed the brain teaser. Thanks for asking this.